# How to pass credential from Site A to Site B without displaying credential at address bar

Tags: credentials

I have 3 site.

- Site A : Just a login form.
- Site B : an Icewarp webmail
- Site C : Lotus domino mail

For now, i dont want include Site C in my question. It just for Site A and Site B

I want when a user login to Site A and then, automatically redirected to Site B. How do i pass the credential safely without the username and password being displayed?

My current script is below : This is the script when user login to Site A, and then passing the credential.

```
if ($mailhost == "icewarp")
                      {
                            Header("refresh:0;url=Site B icewarp URL/webmail/index.html?!#$pid:$credential");
                            exit;
                      }
                    elseif ($mailhost == "domino")
                      {
                           Header("refresh:0;url=Site C Domino URL/mail/domadmin.nsf?Login&Username=$pid&Password=$credential");
                            exit;
                      }
```

The system is working fine, but the problem is user credential is being displayed on address bar. How do i send user credential in alternate way?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to encrypt the credentials. Probably is the only truly secure way.

You can encrypt it with: [mcrypt-encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).
Then, decrypt with: [mcrypt-decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and POST the values to the Domino login form as opposed to placing them in the address bar which forms a GET request.

For PHP - Three different was to make a POST request.
http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php